# Why Is The Artificer's Infuse Item So Confusing?

Tags: dnd-5e, class, artificer, artificer-infusions

I'm playing an artificer in my friends campaign but I tend to get confused by a lot of the wording on Infuse Item. The ability seems simple enough but it feels like I'm missing something because the lack of specificity makes the ability seem like complete nonsense.

For starters certain magic items this ability can create such as an [alchemy jug](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/alchemy-jug) can only be used once per day. If that's the case then can I just use the item, then keep creating more until I run out of infusions?

Also, can I uninfuse an item by choice? The game says "Moreover, no object can bear more than one of your infusions at a time. If you try to exceed your maximum number of infusions, the oldest infusion immediately ends, and then the new infusion applies." Does this mean the only way to remove an infusion is to create a new infusion and have the oldest one disappear? what if you think the newer one is less useful in the current situation? do you get to choose which one becomes uninfused or is the oldest one always destroyed?

There's a bunch of other questions I have about this ability but I can't figure out how to put them into words because they're just so confusing.

Comment: Related: [Can my artificer use an Infusion to create a Bag of Holding everyday for profit?](/questions/166886)

Comment: We have a one-question-per-post policy here. Please split these questions up and ask each one separately.